# Wordpress migration loses icons

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, font-awesome

I have a wordpress website to migrate to another server. At the moment I am testing the result of the migration that is done using All In One Migration plugin. You can see [here](https://puck.io/) the original website instead [here](https://puck-io-staging.puckapp.live/) the result of the migration.

Beside minor things like email addresses and image sizes to fix looks good but I can't figure out how to fix the icons that appear like this:

[image]

These are custom icons uploaded in Avada plugin and I can see that they are not showing in the admin page either:

[image]

Compared to the original website:

[image]

I already tried the most common suggestions I found like reset Avada's cache and reset icons cache but still can't figure out how to fix it.

Some general information:

- The new server is hosted in AWS Lightsail with Wordpress blueprint
- The original website runs PHP 7 and the new one runs PHP 8 (hopefully it doesn't matter because I can't downgrade the blueprint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason may be that some links use http instead of https

[image]

Comment: Yes, probably is that. I literally the icons get blocked `downloadable font: failed to start download (font-family: "puck_custom" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:2): content blocked source: http://puck-io-staging.puckapp.live/wp-content/uploads/fusion-icons/puck_custom-v1.0-4/fonts/puck_custom.woff?vbmi1g `. Any idea about how to fix it? I am not a WP developer and I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: Check links from the control panel
Settings -> General
WordPress Address (URL) 
Site Address (URL)

Comment: Yes, that was it. I just had to change the values by editing `wp-config.php` because the bitami image doesn't allow to do it via interface.

Answer (score 0):

seems you have mixed content in a few instances this should help with at least fixing those errors.
[https://www.plesk.com/blog/various/mixed-content-warnings/#:~:text=If%20a%20hard%20coded%20image,directly%20editing%20your%20theme%20files](https://www.plesk.com/blog/various/mixed-content-warnings/#:%7E:text=If%20a%20hard%20coded%20image,directly%20editing%20your%20theme%20files).

Your hosting may give you a CMD for your server if so you can follow this guide here https://kinsta.com/blog/mixed-content-warnings/